# CLI error on an amazon ec2 when trying to copy file from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services

An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the `ListObjects` operation:

> Missing required header for this request: `x-amz-content-sha256`

Answer (score 0):

check your ~/.aws/config file and add proper region value.
or 
re run aws configure

Answer (score 0):

This misleading error shows up when you haven’t authenticated properly. Validate that either
* your `~/.aws/config` is correct.
* you’re providing API keys properly at invocation time.
* your environment variables are passing your credentials properly.
* the instance you’re running this from has the proper permissions assigned to its IAM role.